# Encrypt other person's public key to reduce overall needed key size, viable?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, memory-efficient

I need to use RSA encryption in a environment where byte size of the keys are important. 
I don't want to risk security breaking, so I wondered if you could have one person transmit his key first using (2048 bit) and then have the other transmit his key of size (256bit) encrypted with the other guy's key. And if this would still provide a secure scheme?

PS: I realize 256 bit would increase from the encryption and you can ignore the man-in-middle problem.

TL;DR: Does keeping public key secret allow for a smaller key size?

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would use RSA and other asymmetric algorithms specifically for the purpose of exchanging keys.  The security of RSA has to do with factoring large primes, which is why their key sizes are typically so much longer than symmetric keys for algorithms such as AES.  What you don't want to do is reduce the RSA key size in your scheme.  So if what you're doing is creating a 256 bit AES key and then using AES thereafter for encryption I think the security scheme will work.  Public key cryptography is much slower than symmetric encryption therefore for performance and other reasons you don't want to use RSA.

As to your question regarding keeping the public key secret, I think that goes against what RSA is meant for.  A public key is meant to be public.

The implementation can have failings as well, for example SSL 3 was found to have a padding oracle vulnerability in 2014.  I would suggest you use a standard implementation like [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) rather than trying to make your own protocol.  Secure protocols are typically the most difficult problems in cryptography.

Comment: Talk about not being able to see the forest for the trees. Yes that makes perfect sense, I always just assumed RSA was used for everything but that would ofc be stupid.